# Merge text and Json files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, json

I have a text file that looks like this

```
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz
```

Have a JSON file that looks like this.

```
{
    "TagSet": [test:tag]
}
{
    "TagSet": [foo:bar]
}
```

I'd like to merge these files in a way that the output will look like this.

```
    AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started       
{
            "TagSet": [test:tag]
        }
    AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz    
{
            "TagSet": [foo:bar]
        }
```

or this.

```
   AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started       
                    "TagSet": [test:tag]
            
        AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz    
                    "TagSet": [foo:bar]
```

I tried using

```
paste input.txt output.json | pr -t -e24
```

But its not giving me the output that I am looking.

Here's the output I am getting when I run AWS CLI.

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-1-188-228 ~]$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket tesXXXXXnkins --query 'Contents[?LastModified<=`2021-09-07T00:00:00`].{Key:Key}' --output text | xargs -n 1 aws s3api get-object-tagging   --bucket testXXXXXkins --key
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
{
    "TagSet": []
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please explain _in words_ the logic of the merging.

Comment: Sure. Here's the original question. As you can see I'd like to generate a report showing which object have which tags. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916551/get-tags-for-all-objects-in-an-s3-bucket This is going to be an interim solution for now until we find a better one

Comment: Thanks, but that... doesn't really clarify much. Please [edit] your question and explain how exactly you want the files to be merged. How can we know what tag should be placed about which section of your JSON? How should we deal with nested tags (like the last one you have in your SO question which, by the way, you don't mention here). Should there be one tag inserted for each occurrence of the string `"TagSet":` in the JSON? For each new set of `{`?

Comment: Neither input nor output seems to be valid JSON. Consider updating your question to include the actual data, or at least data that may be parsed by a JSON parser. For eth output, are you ok with not having that as a JSON file, or do you actually want JSON output with the pathnames as values of some key in the JSON file? It's a bit unclear what the end goal is here .

Comment: That's the output I am getting when I run the aws cli. I have updated the question.

Comment: Can we assume that: you have a file with a newline-separated list of strings that maps 1 to 1 to a list of objects at the root level of a well-formed JSON file, and that you want to output corresponding (based on the order they appear in each file) pairs of one line from the string list and one object from the JSON object list? Is the indentation you are showing in the desired output relevant? If yes, which rules should it follow?

Comment: Hi Fra-san, Yes, it maps 1 to 1 to a list of objects at the root level. Correct, I'd like to output corresponding (based on the order they appear in each file. The indentation doesn't matter much as long as the json entry is below the text entry.

Answer (score 0):

Making some assumptions, namely that:

- you have a file with a newline-separated list of strings that maps one to one to a list of objects at the root level of a well-formed JSON file;
- you want to output corresponding (based on the order they appear in each file) pairs of one line from the string list and one object from the JSON object list;
- the indentation of the output (as shown in your question) is not relevant;

given the input data:

```
$ cat input.txt
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz
```

```
$ cat input.json
{
  "TagSet": []
}
{
  "TagSet": [
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

using [`jq`](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) and `paste` (in a shell that supports the ANSI C `$'string'` quoting style, such as Bash), you can write:

```
$ jq -rc < input.json '.' | paste -d $'\n' input.txt -
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started
{"TagSet":[]}
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz
{"TagSet":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
```

The `-c` option instructs `jq` to print each object on a single line, ensuring `paste` will print a whole JSON object after each line from `input.txt`.

With a bit more of typing, using `jq`'s ability to pretty-print its output (and again assuming Bash):

```
$ readarray -t lines < input.txt
$ jq -r -s \
  'range($ARGS.positional | length) as $i | $ARGS.positional[$i], .[$i]' \
  --args "${lines[@]}" < input.json
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started
{
  "TagSet": []
}
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz
{
  "TagSet": [
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each line from `input.txt` is read into an element of the `lines` shell array, which is then expanded as a list of positional arguments passed to `jq`.
The `-s` option makes `jq` read the list of objects from `input.json` into an array, instead of executing the filter program once for each one of them.
Based on the length (*`n`*) of the array of positional arguments, the `jq` script iterates over the `1` to *`n`* range using the *`i`* index and prints pairs made of the *`i`*th positional argument and the *`i`*th JSON object. This is done using the `exp as $identifier | ...` construct, which runs the right hand side filter (`...`) on the whole input data for each value of the `exp` expression (which is made available in the right hand side filter as `$identifier`).

Answer (score 0):

I'm making the same sort of assumptions as fra-san [in their answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676939/493832), i.e. that there is a well-formed JSON document with some structure similar to

```json
{"TagSet":[]}
{"TagSet":[{"foo":"bar"}]}
```

... and that there is a text file with an equal number of lines as there are objects in the JSON input,

```
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started
AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz
```

You may insert the pathnames (for want of a better word) from the text file in the corresponding JSON objects under a new key called `pathname` so that the first pathname becomes the value of the `pathname` key in the first object, etc.

```bsh
jq -Rn --slurpfile j input.json '$j[] | .pathname = input' input.txt
```

The above command starts by reading the existing JSON document in `input.json` into the `jq` array `$j`. It then iterates over the elements of that array, i.e., over the objects of the JSON file, and for each, it creates a `pathname` key with the value given by the return value of the function `input`.

The `input` function returns the next input data.  In this case, we make sure both `-R` and `-n` are in effect, giving us "raw input" rather than JSON input, and avoiding reading the whole `input.txt` file automatically as soon as the processing starts, respectively. This means that "the next input" is the subsequent line from `input.txt`, our text file.

The effect of the above is to add a line from `input.txt` as the value for a new key, `pathname`, for each object in the JSON file `input.json`.

The output would look like this:

```json
{
  "TagSet": [],
  "pathname": "AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/_started"
}
{
  "TagSet": [
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  ],
  "pathname": "AWSDynamoDB/01629227303395-c3801363/data/57sxfwx54y63xo46yhna6qgf3e.json.gz"
}
```

Extracting the pathnames corresponding objects that has a `TagSet` containing `{foo:"bar"}` could then be done using the above as input in `data.json` with the command

```bsh
jq -r 'select(any(.TagSet[]; . == {foo:"bar"})).pathname' data.json
```

This reads the data and selects the objects where any of the `TagSet` array's elements are `{foo:"bar"}`.  From these objects, it extracts the `pathname` key's value.